# How do I parse "17/10/2016 6:52:13" into a DateTime

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse the datetime: `17/10/2016 6:52:13` as text to `DateTime` but I always get `01/01/0001` as output.

My code is:

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy" + " " + "hh:mm:ss",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeStamp);
```

Any clue?

Comment: `TryParseExact` returns boolean result of parsing, you simply ignore it.

Comment: @dave Please don't add tags to titles unless it is necessary.

Comment: @slugster sure thing (although in my defence it was already in the title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input only has one digit for the hour, but your format string uses two. Also, since you don't have an AM/PM specifier, you probably intend to use 24-hour time, which requires a capital `H`.

Try `"dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"` instead.

See [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier) for more details.

Comment: Of course, this will break for inputs with two-digit hours.

Comment: @ChrisShain: No it won't. 11 or 12 work just fine with this format. So do 01, 02, etc.

Comment: It works if he's not using a 24 hours hours format like 16:35:29

Comment: Right- it works fine for "10"-"12" as an hour, not for "13"-"23".

Comment: But the 24 hours format is the most used in the word, so it's a good assumption that it may not work.

Comment: Good point. I originally had a capital "H" in there, but didn't want to stray too far from the example. Now that I look at it again, there's no AM/PM specifier, so he's probably going for 24-hr time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
string givenDate = "17/10/2016 06:52:13";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(givenDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or you could simply use the "h:mm:ss" considering your given time was 6:52:13